# django override model save method error

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model, which contains an ImageField. I want to autocreate 2 additional fields from that ImageField.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    ...
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    #for autocreating 
    rimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='rimg', null=True, blank=True)
    limg = models.ImageField(upload_to='limg', null=True, blank=True)

    def create_rimg(self):
        # some work for generating rimg
        self.rimg.save()

    def create_limg(self):
        # some work for generating limg
        self.limg.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_rimg()
        self.create_limg()
        force_update = False

        if self.id:
            force_update = True

        super(Images, self).save(force_update=force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

That code gives a 500 error. If i call that code, it works perfect:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_rimg()
        #self.create_limg() 
        force_update = False
```

or

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #self.create_rimg()
        self.create_limg() 
        force_update = False
```

How can i call that 2 functions in save() method?

Comment: You'll need to show us the actual error.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman said post the full stacktrace from the errorpage. Can be related to some synchronous problem because of uploading time. But it is speculation until you show the full error.